# Getting facebook (oAuth) login to work with Cordova, using Polymer and Firebase

Tags: cordova, firebase, polymer, intel-xdk

I have a simple polymer chat app. There is a login button that uses Firebase's oAuth Facebook integration. When I wrap it into an Android Cordova app the login button does nothing.

Things I've done so far.

Changed Polymers on-tap to on-click as I think there is an issue with launching a pop-up with an on-tap?

Changed the default action with firebase from redirect to popup as Cordova dosent support redirect apparently.

Installed plugin In-app browser as that might be a prerequisite.

Now I'm out of ideas.

I'm using Intel XDK to build the Cordova Android App. I'm also using a Crosswalk version of Android.

Comment: In order for Firebase OAuth popups to work within the Cordova environment, you must (a) have the InAppBrowser plugin installed, and (b) `cordova.js` must be included.

On the page where you invoke `ref.authWithOAuthPopup(...)`, try `console.log(cordova)`. Is `cordova` in scope, or undefined?

Next, on the same page, try `window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');`. Is the app loading in the *InAppBrowser*, where you can see the popup frame with an option to close, or is the entire page being redirected? If the latter, dig into why the *InAppBrowser* is not available.

Comment: You might want to check this out.  It uses Ionic Framework, but you can certainly use the knowledge and make adjustments to fit your needs.  https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/03/sign-into-firebase-with-facebook-using-ionic-framework/